# How to calculate signal to noise ratio (SNR) from a list (sequence) of amplitude?

Tags: noise, snr

Suppose I have a list of amplitude (straight line signal):

```
x = [1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1]
```

By intuition, zero value in list x  makes the noise of straight signal.

If we modified some value, such as 2, we get more noise level.

```
y = [1,1,1,0,1,2,1,1]
```

Hence by my intuition, SNR of list x is greater than SNR of list y.

So how do I calculate SNR from a list?

I know that formula of SNR basically if signal amplitude is voltage.

```
SNR = 20*log(S_i/N_i)
```

Where `S_i` is value of a list signal in an index.

But I have no idea how to get `N_i`.

Assume we are using volt unit.

I expect I can compute SNR programmatically from scratch without any external library with python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$SNR = 10 * log((\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} s(i)^2) / (\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} n(i)^2))$$

Where $N$ is the length of the signal, $s(i)$ is signal amplitudes/magnitude and $n(i)$ is noise amplitude/magnitude.

In Your case the summation of noise signal for y is 2 and that of x is 1 hence SNR of x is more than y.

In your case where You are defining the signal to be "straight signal", the original signal can be considered as $[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]$. Let's call this X

noise in signal $n_x = X - x  = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]$

and

noise in signal $n_y = X - y  = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0]$

Comment: Do I need to normalize the data, it seems you normalize to 0.

Comment: Normalization was not applied on the signal.